# How get keys to JSON as Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I receive the following string is supposed JSON

```
{\"CUPS\":\"890201\",\"Cama\":\"\",\"Cantidad\":1,\"Cargo_Autorizador\":\"\",\"Cargo_Remisor\":\"\",\"Celular_Autorizador\":\"\",\"Celular_Protegido\":\"30129193\",\"Celular_Remisor\":\"\",\"Ciudad_Autorizador\":\"BOGA - CUNDIRCA\",\"Cod_Descripcion\":\"\",\"Codigo_Entidad_Pagadora\":\"EP002    \",\"Codigo_Prestador\":\"152310\",\"Consecutivo_Impresion_Web\":\"\",\"DescripcionErrorNegocio\":null,\"Diagnóstico\":\"-M25.5\",\"Direccion_Autorizador\":\"AV N° 66A-27       \",\"Direccion_Prestador\":\"AV N° 66A-27       \"}
```

But to serialize the NSDictionary I left with the spaces of the Key but nill

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:encodData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

in the log:

```
json=(NSDictionary *) 62 key/value pairs
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

I try to pass data from each key to a NSArray

```
NSArray *typeArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[json valueForKey:@"CUPS"]];
```

but it generates an error

```
'-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb28ab973f0'
```

I need to get the value of each key on a NSArray

Comment: The value of "CUPS" isn't an array, it's a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the keys of your json data, then do it like this:

```
NSArray *typeArray=[json allKeys];
```

---

Your question is not clear to be honest, but here is a way to enumerate both values and keys:

```
for (id key in [json allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"key = %@ | value = %@", key, [json valueForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: I need to get the value of each key on a diferent NSArray

Comment: @lycros then my post answer your question

Answer (score 0):

From your JSON it's clear that the `[json valueForKey:@"CUPS"]` returns a `NSString` not a `NSArray`.

If you need to retrieve all values from the dictionary you can use:

```
NSArray *typeArray = [json allValues];
```